# How to supply the password as an argument in realm join to active directory command

Tags: linux, shell, active-directory

I am trying to automate few areas like joining the linux server to active directory. To join the server to AD, I am using the following command:

`realm join -U <Username> exmaple.com`

The above command will prompt for a password which need to provided during the execution time. My requirement is to supply the password as an argument in realm join command just like

`realm join -U <Username> -P <Password> example.com` --> This is not working

Can someone help me to figure out the way to supply the password as an argument here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is resolved. Following is the answer

`echo $password | realm join -U <Username> example.com`

replace $password with your actual password